# How to prove that $E(M_n 1_{F})=E(M_r 1_{F})$ for a discrete-time martingale $M_n$ with $r>n$?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

For a discrete-time martingale $M_n$ ($\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable), fix $r>n$ and an event $F\in \mathcal{F}_n$, why do we have
$$
E(M_n 1_{F})=E(M_r 1_{F})
$$
from the tower law and property of martingale?

My idea:

Since $r>n$, we have $\mathcal{F}_n\subset \mathcal{F}_r$. Then $M_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_r$-measurable?

Also, for event $F_{r-1}\in \mathcal{F}_{r}$, using martingale property
$$
E(E(M_r 1_{F})\mid F_{r-1})=E(1_{F}E(M_r\mid F_{r-1}))=E(1_{F}M_{r-1})=\cdots=E(1_{F}M_{n})?
$$

Comment: Your proof is almost complete. To make things simpler, you can take of the expectation conditional of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}_n$ so that $\mathbf{E}[M_r\mathbf{1}_F] = \mathbf{E}[\mathbf{E}[M_r\mathbf{1}_F\mid \mathcal{F}_n]] = \mathbf{E}[\mathbf{1}_F\mathbf{E}[M_r\mid\mathcal{F}_n]]=\mathbf{E}[M_n\mathbf{1}_F]$.

Comment: Please include your "property of martingales".  In the discrete case, some authors only define it for the "one-step" case, in which case you'd need to prove the result by induction on $r-n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you need the tower property, just the definition should do. We have that $\mathbb{E}[M_r|\mathcal{F}_n]$ is defined to be the unique random variable such that $\mathbb{E}[M_r|\mathcal{F}_n]$ is $\mathcal{F}_n-$measurable and $$\mathbb{E}[M_r 1_F] = \int_F M_r dP = \int_F \mathbb{E}[M_r|\mathcal{F}_n]dP $$
for all $F\in\mathcal{F}_n$.  If $M_n$ is a discrete time martingale, we will have that $\mathbb{E}[M_r|\mathcal{F}_n] = M_n$. Thus the statement above becomes
$$\mathbb{E}[M_r 1_F] =  \int_F \mathbb{E}[M_r|\mathcal{F}_n]dP =\int_F M_n dP = \mathbb{E}[M_n1_F]$$

Comment: Thanks! I want to ask another quick question. Is $M_n$ $\mathcal{F}_r-$measurable?

Comment: You are really just giving a proof of the tower property here.

Comment: "If $M_n$ is a discrete time martingale, we will have that $\mathbb{E}[M_r|\mathcal{F}_n] = M_n$." - I would be concerned this is begging the question for OP.  Some authors introduce discrete-time martingales only using $$\mathbb{E}[M_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n] = M_n$$

Comment: @quasAliki yes since $\{\mathcal{F}_m\}$ forms a filtration so that $\mathcal{F}_n\subset \mathcal{F}_r$ and we know that $M_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_n-$measurable